# Automatic 'created by user' field using django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

#### models.py

```
class Nugget(TimeStampedModel):
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='added_by', blank=True, null=True)
```

#### serializers.py

```
class NuggetSerializer(TaggitSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    added_by = serializers.CreateOnlyDefault(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

#### views.py

```
class NuggetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Nugget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NuggetSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(added_by=self.request.user)
```

#### What I'm trying to achieve:

`added_by` should:

1. Be set on `create` of a `Nugget`
2. Default to the `user` who created the `Nugget`, with no way to override this default
3. Be included and shown when a `Nugget` is retrieved
4. Not be shown as an option for `create/POST` in the browsable API
5. Not be editable after `create`

Comment: Just remove `added_by` from your serializer altogether, and prevent it from being auto-generated using `exclude`. You can still pass it while saving, kwargs passed to `save` are simply copied onto the model.

Comment: @spectras If I `exclude` `added_by`, then it doesn't meet requirement No. 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed `added_by` in `serializers.py` (wasn't using a field, and set to read_only) and `.save()` in `views.py` to stop overriding the default.

`CurrentUserDefault()` requires `request` within the `context` dict. In this case `generics.ListCreateAPIView` already does that.

#### models.py

```
class Nugget(TimeStampedModel):
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='added_by', blank=True, null=True)
```

#### serializers.py

```
class NuggetSerializer(TaggitSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
        added_by = serializers.StringRelatedField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), read_only=True)
```

#### views.py

```
class NuggetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Nugget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NuggetSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

Comment: Great you were able to fix your issue. You may accept your own answer if it solves your question.

Comment: I think it won't add the user (added_by) unless you provide it in the save(added_by=request.user) as argument as done by some other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I did it the following way (no need to make the field nullable):

**models.py**

```
class Nugget(models.Model):
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name='added_by', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class NuggetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    added_by = serializers.StringRelatedField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Nugget
        fields = ['added_by']
```

**views.py**

```
class NuggetList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Nugget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NuggetSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        request = serializer.context["request"]
        serializer.save(added_by=request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to update `views.py` to make it work:

```
class NuggetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Nugget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NuggetSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        req = serializer.context['request']
        serializer.save(added_by=req.user)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it does not require your model field to be nullable and blankable. The other solutions need you to make that field nullable, which might cause db inconsistencies in the long term.